# Remove axis scaling in periodogram in R

Tags: r

I plot periodogram using spec.pgram but I don't want to use logarithmic Y scale. How can I remove it?
[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then `spec.pgram` produces on object of the class `spec` which are plotted using the `plot.spec` method, which is described in the documentation as follows:

> Plotting Spectral Densities Plotting method for objects of class
>   "spec". For multivariate time series it plots the marginal spectra of
>   the series or pairs plots of the coherency and phase of the
>   cross-spectra.

This method uses an argument `log` to specify whether or not the y-axis will use the logarithmic Y scale. You can lose the logarithmic scale by setting it to "no".

```
# code based on the example in the plot.spec documentation
require(graphics)
spectrum(mdeaths, spans = c(3,3))

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(mfdeaths.spc, log = "yes")
plot(mfdeaths.spc, log = "no")
dev.off
```

[image: spec plots]